# Purchase app from another app using In-App Purchase

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase

I am trying to implement In-App Purchase in iPhone SDK, but I am trying to buy an app from another app.

Is it possible to implement it? From first app, I open one feature which is locked by In-App Purchase. It has to install the feature as another app in the device. So that the owner can get the money of the app using In-App Purchase.

Comment: what have you tried ? did you look into IAP documentation? It is possible. See LINE app for example.

Comment: I checked the IAP documentation, But its said we can purchase only digital documentation. I want to purchase an app from another app. Eg in my first app i have an icon of an application, when i clicked on that icon In app purchase process starts, when i enter details another app will install in our device, When i clicked on the icon again the first app goes background and the second one opens. Is it possible? If so can you suggest any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot purchase an app from an app using In-App purchase for that go through below point:

> 11.1
>
> Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality with
>   mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

And for more details please [check](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html#purchasing-currencies). If any issue please revert me.